# Raspberry pi imager return 404 while flashing OS in SD Card

Tags: pi-4, ubuntu, raspberry-pi-imager

I have a Raspberry Pi 400 4GB with Ubuntu Server 21.10 64-bit OS installed.
I decided to install ubuntu server again because I broke the OS so I decided to reinstall the OS using Pi Imager utility tool,
but for some reason I can't download the OS from the servers using the tool attached a Screenshot.

Error says the server returns 404 code. but when I use the same IP to browse using chrome I can see the contents of the file.

although I can successfully install raspberry pi OS using an .img file

please help

Version:
raspberry Pi imager 1.5.1
trying to flash Ubuntu Server 21.10 - 64-bit
as Windows 11- 64-bit Host computer
on a 16 GB microSD card

[image: Image Attachment with chrome showing the content of the IP address]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Ubuntu-server images were temporarily unavailable so the imager was not able to fetch them. A bug report was submitted on the website and the server files were made available again.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried updating your Imager on your Windows 11 PC? Imager version 1.5.1 is quite old in comparison to the current version.

Comment: yes, the same happened with the 1.7.1 version. the problem was with the ubuntu website actually not responding. I submitted a bug report on the site so it got resolved